# Is it possible to create a new folder in MediaLibrary?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have read the msdn pages to only found that it seems I can only save the image to the one called "Saved Pitures" and "Camera Roll".
But I want to create a folder for my app specifically.
(Because I don't want to mess with those pictures that is not create by my app.)
I see there is an Albums properties under MediaLibrary. Can I do something with it, like, create a new album?
What that I want to achieve is, I need to create a folder that can be seen in the "Pictures" app and able to save pictures on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot create your own folders in the media library. The only way to associate a photo in the media library with your app is through [Lenses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206990).