# How to create a new folder in Pictures Folder in phone memory on windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm new in developing windows phone 8 applications and i want to know how can I create a new folder in pictures folder in phone memory. An example would be great! In these pictures is showing the location where i want to create the new folder What capabilities should I declare for this purpose?
Here is my code but it doesn't work.

```
StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
StorageFolder myFolder = await folder.CreateFolderAsync("MyNewFolder", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
StorageFile myFile = await myFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyInformation.txt");
using (StreamWriter f = new StreamWriter(myFile.Path))
{
    f.WriteLine("ABC");
    f.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you added the Picture Library Capability in your project?

Comment: I only added MEDIALIB_PHOTO capability in WMAppManifest.xml. I have to add Picture Library Capability there too or in AppManifest.xml?
I am developing windowws phone 8 if it metters.

Comment: You cannot create your own folder in picture library.refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856685/is-it-possible-to-create-a-new-folder-in-medialibrary)

Comment: I saw this, but i don't want to save pictures. I just want to save a file anywhere in phone memory that user can see and access it.

Comment: Do you know a way @SaurabhSrivastava ?

Comment: what it is..tell me also please

Comment: You can't do this on windows phone 8. You need to download visual studio 2013, to open your project in it and to click right on project. There you will have something like "target for windows phone 8.1". Click it and the you will can do it

Comment: And still you will can write the code like in vs 2012. You will not have to learn new programming style for vs 2013. Hope this will help you too.

Comment: If you have problem with accessing it let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows phone 8 sdCard is read only. In windows phone 8.1 or higher sdCard is writable